# Doublepointer with Strings in C / Pointers to Array with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, free

Can Someone explain to me why the first pointer (stringarray[0]) is missing in my output and how to solve it. also I'd like to know how I can free my memory of all malloc pointers.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

[...]

char ** stringarray;
if (( stringarray = (char **)malloc(counter*sizeof(char)))== NULL){exit(0);}

int k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < len; i =i+1){
    if((strcmp(countries, districts[i]) == 0) && ( argvIntPeoplelimit <= people[i])) {
        if (( stringarray[k] = (char * ) malloc(100*sizeof(char)))== NULL){exit(0);}

        snprintf(stringarray[k],100,"The Country %s has %d people.",countries[i],people[i]);
        printf("%d %d %s %s %d\n",i,k,stringarray[k], countires[i],people[i] ); //here stringarray[k] k==0 has a value
        k=k+1;
    }  
}
write_file(stringarray,counter);
for (int f = 0; f < k; ++f)
{
    // if i call stringarray[0] nothing shows up


    //ERROR can't free(stringarray);

}
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to build up the structure pointers with strings that allows me to the handle the data over to " char *result[]" of write_file function.

```
void write_file(char *result[], int len);
```

Any help, tips, hints are great appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the correct way for allocating memory for an array of strings:

```
// number of pointers/strings; don't have to cast the result of malloc
char** stringArray = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);

// allocate however many chars for each pointer
for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    stringArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

strcpy(stringArray[0], "Hello");
strcpy(stringArray[1], "world!");

printf("%s %s\n", stringArray[0], stringArray[1]);
```

And for freeing the above, you'd do this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    free(stringArray[i]);

free(stringArray);
```

Comment: Could you add to your code respectivly that it takes values from snprintf()?

Answer (score 1):

Why to make things so complicated
Avoid memory allocation, if your intent is to dump the data in to file

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i =i+1){
if((strcmp(countries, districts[i]) == 0) && ( argvIntPeoplelimit <= people[i])) {
    char country_inf[256] = {0};
    int info_len;
    info_len = snprintf(country_inf,sizeof(country_inf),"The Country %s has %d people.",countries[i],people[i]);
    write_file(country_inf,info_len);
}
```

}

write_file should open file in append mode and write the new data in to file. No allocation no free

Still if you want to use. Your first allocation is wrong. It should be sizeof(char*)

```
stringarray = (char **)malloc(counter*sizeof(char*))
```

Comment: Can you help me here out again? Let's say I sadly cannot append to the file - just write all the data in one call - and the memory allocation is a requirement as well :( The point is to understand pointers. int counter tells me how many results are found with the strcmp() functions that runs here a second time ... which is in use equal to k. Could be the problem that allocating stringarray and stringarray[0] is the same address?